# MySQL - Importing data without a primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am developing an application for use within my department at work. The application needs to access a list of people that is supplied by my company.

This is kind of a mess, though, as my company does not maintain very clean data and that situation cannot be changed. I will use sample table names and such here for brevity.

Here is the current workflow for how I get this data into my database:

1. I receive a monthly report, in Excel (XLSX) format from my company.
2. Convert the report to CSV.
3. Delete all items from the current `[people]` table
4. Import the CSV data into the `[people]` table

I can not change this process to simple UPDATE or INSERT statements due to several factors:

1. There is a lot of duplicate data in the reports I receive
2. Each `person` can be listed in the report multiple times, with slight variations in the data in each column (ie: they may have several entries for each `person` but with different addresses for each row).
3. My company uses two "IDs" to identify the `person`, but they recycle these IDs. If a person is deleted from their records, for example, they may take that person's ID and assign it to a new person.

Without making the entire row the PK, is there any way to salvage this situation to create a true table that can be accurately referenced from another?

Comment: I would suggest you start sending out your CV. Recycling IDs is not going to end well.

Comment: Possibly instead of taking whole row as PK you can generate proper id per person as md5(concat(ID1,ID2)) or use other encryption function. They are not 100% unique but collisions are unlikely.

Comment: You don't need database design, you need business analysis. What does the person you are doing this for want you do with this pile of unclear stuff? You can read about 'data cleansing'.